# Bitbucket project clone results in missing System.web.MVC dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bitbucket

I've started working on project recently, that is on Bitbucket. Everything is running fine. Just one issue occurs to my partner when She tries to clone a repository on her side, the references to "System.Web.Mvc" in two layers shows yellow colored warning icon, Which I know obviously mean "not found".

But not getting the reason why this reference always show "not found" icon?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the dll included in the project? If you check it out to a "naked" system, will it have the file?

Comment: Most of the time shared projects are setup with NuGet auto-restore. The dependencies will show up as yellow icons by default until you build the project - then they will download into the cloned application's packages directory. Did you try building the project after cloning it?

Comment: @Fildor can't see the dll in project location.

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes I tried building the project, but this error didn't resolve.

Comment: How did you import it in your Environment? Via NuGet? Seems to me it is getting ignored by your Version Control System (is it git?). This *can* make sense if it is supposed to be handled by NuGet as NighOwl888 already said. Maybe have a look into the NuGet Manager Settings for your project. It should either be included in your version control or be restored by NuGet. If both does not apply, it will be missing.